# How to deploy Java application on different OS?

Tags: java, deployment, operating-system

I'm supposing I have built a nice desktop application written in Java and I want to distribute it to some friends, colleagues, customers,.. in order to use it on their everyday business.
Many of them uses Windows, other OSX and no one of them knows Java or programming, they are simple users of computer, so Outlook, Google Chrome, ad-hoc softwares for business (crm, management, ..).
I don't want to annoy them saying 'You have to install Java prior to execute the jar file' because makes my software less nice than it really is, and makes the installation not user-friendly.

Is there a way to deploy a Java application in exe, dmg, pkg,.. formats in order to have an installation wizard with custom options (such as 'Company Name', 'Telephone', 'Where do you want to install?', 'Serial code',...), an easy auto-created icon on the desktop to launch the software, an uninstaller to eventually remove the files, and a prior check of the Java version (if installed check the version and eventually 'Follow this link to update Java', if not 'Please follow this link and download Java')?

Comment: "Is there a way?" This question is trivial, but the answer to the follow-up question is not. Closing as too broad

Comment: I'm asking a precise question. Is there a way to deploy a Java application in exe or dmg? It's not too broad.

Comment: Maybe [Lauch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) could be helpful.

Comment: Java Web Start is designed for such goals

Comment: No, your question is fine. It's just that there are numerous ways that you could try to solve this, but listing and comparing them all is too broad (IMO) for this site

Comment: IMO having more than one solution is better for everyone.

Comment: It's a precise question, but it's off-topic. See [help/on-topic]. The problem is that it is either asking us for a full, very broad explanation of the process of building applications on each of those OSs, or it's asking us for external tools. Both of these are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Java Web Start?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javawebstart/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. I've used [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) installer along with [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) and with almost all the features you described.